# one-column multicol environment

Tags: multicol

I'm writing some `xsl` that takes `xml` source and outputs a `.tex` file. The source has an element that is meant to frequently become a `multicols` environment in the `.tex` output, and it has a `cols` attribute to specify how many columns there are.

I'd like the default to be one column if no `cols` attribute has been specified. But it appears that `\begin{multicols}{1}` still produces two-column output. I could write the `xsl` in a casewise way and skip the `multicols` environment altogether when `cols` is not specified (or is specified as `1`), but for the sake of consistency I'd prefer not to.

Is there any LaTeX way to get the `multicols` environment to produce one-column output?

Comment: clearly this is possible -- the `multicol` documentation (`texdoc multicol`) contains single-column segments, such as the start of section 4.  the source for that document would show how it's done.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I can't find the source but I would assume it achieves single-column by simply not invoking the `multicols` environment. If I were writing a one-off `.tex` file, that would be fine. But the `xsl` element to this question is pushing me to try to make `\begin{multicols}{1}` work.

Comment: the source is `multicol.dtx` and the relevant section begins `\begin{multicols}{2}[\section{The Implementation}
%         We are now switching to two-column output ...]` there's also a `\subsection` within the scope of the optional argument.  but definitely not `\begin{multicols}{1}`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This solution is inspired by Werner's, but it supports the optional argument to `\begin{multicols}` and, more importantly, doesn't collect the whole contents in a single swoop, which is best to avoid, if possible. It also doesn't require changing the environment's name.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol,lipsum,xparse}

\let\multicolmulticols\multicols
\let\endmulticolmulticols\endmulticols

\RenewDocumentEnvironment{multicols}{mO{}}
 {%
  \ifnum#1=1
    #2%
  \else % More than 1 column
    \multicolmulticols{#1}[#2]
  \fi
 }
 {%
  \ifnum#1=1
  \else % More than 1 column
    \endmulticolmulticols
  \fi
 }

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}[\section{Title in single column}]
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{multicols}

\begin{multicols}{1}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You can use an alternative environment which conditions on whether you're managing a single or multiple columns:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol,lipsum,environ}

\NewEnviron{auxmulticols}[1]{%
  \ifnum#1<2\relax% Fewer than 2 columns
    %\vspace{-\baselineskip}% Possible vertical correction
    \BODY
  \else% More than 1 column
    \begin{multicols}{#1}
      \BODY
    \end{multicols}%
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\begin{auxmulticols}{2}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{auxmulticols}

\begin{auxmulticols}{1}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{auxmulticols}

\end{document}
```

[`multicol`](http://ctan.org/pkg/multicol) expects to capture the end of the environment in order to gauge where the `multicols` text ends. Wrapping it inside a new environment that captures the entire content in (say) `\BODY` (as is done using [`environ`](http://ctan.org/pkg/environ)) allows you to condition on certain arguments before handling the output.

Comment: The above assumes that you have the capacity to invoke `auxmulticols` rather than `multicols`.

Comment: Yes, I can write the `xsl` to use `auxmulticols`. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol,lipsum,environ}    

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}

your 2 columns text

\end{multicols}

your 1 column text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The question answers your question. It says "I could write the xsl in a casewise way and skip the multicols environment altogether when cols is not specified (or is specified as 1), but for the sake of consistency I'd prefer not to."