# Tikz node vertical alignment & titles added to exercises

Tags: tikz-pgf, formatting, vspace

My question relates to sgmoye's answer to the problem posed in [Inspired exercise Sheet from Indesign](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/355017/inspired-exercise-sheet-from-indesign). I'd like to expand on this answer by having the exercise number vertically aligned with the word 'Exercise'. As you can see from the image below, there is a small vertical space above the red line which means that this currently isn't true. Basically, I'd like to keep the gray border around the white box, but have 'Exercise' level with the number in this white box.

In addition, I'd like to add a different title to each exercise, which should also be vertically aligned with the exercise number. This should sit in the white gap on the right of the given image (outside the tikz rectangle). Can anyone show me how this can be done? I have added the code I am working with.

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX


\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,landscape]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}

\newcounter{exrc}

\newcommand{\exstep}{%
    \stepcounter{exrc}%
    \tikz[baseline]\node[anchor=base,%
        rectangle split,
        rectangle split parts=2,
        draw=gray,
        thick,
        rectangle split horizontal,
        outer sep = 0pt,
        rectangle split part fill={gray,white},
        inner sep=0pt] (exx) at (0,0)
        {\textcolor{white}{\bfseries\extype}\nodepart{two}\textcolor{black}{\bfseries\theexrc}};
}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \draw[thick,rounded corners]
            ($(current page text area.south west)+(-12pt,-12pt)$)
                rectangle 
                ($(current page text area.north east)+(12pt,12pt)$);
        \node[white,fill=gray,rounded corners]
                at ($(current page text area.north)+(0,12pt)$) 
                %% Change `Exercises' to suit
                {\bfseries\sffamily\hspace*{1em}Exercises\hspace*{1em}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

%% There are two environments, `exci` for exercises using `enumerate`,
%% and `exct` for text exercises that do not use `enumerate`.
%% Both have an optional argument to change the name of the
%% exercise on the fly. See the included examples.

\newenvironment{exci}[2][Exercise]{%
    \def\extype{#1}%
    \leavevmode\exstep\par
    \smallskip
    #2
    \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*,noitemsep,nosep]
}{%
    \end{enumerate}
    \bigskip
    \def\extype{Exercise}%
}

\newenvironment{exct}[1][Exercise]{%
    \def\extype{#1}%
    \leavevmode\exstep\par
    \smallskip
    }{%
        \bigskip
        \def\extype{Exercise}%
}

\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
\parindent0pt


\begin{document}

\begin{multicols*}{2}

\begin{exci}{Calculate the following limits:}
\item $$\lim\displaylimits_{x \to2}\frac{4x^3-5x-22}{x^{2}-x-2}$$
\end{exci}


\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `rectangle split part align=base` to the node options. But then you will probably want to increase `inner sep`. I used `inner sep=1pt` in the code below.

[image]

```
\newcommand{\exstep}{%
    \stepcounter{exrc}%
    \tikz[baseline]\node[anchor=base,%
        rectangle split,
        rectangle split parts=2,
        rectangle split part align=base,
        draw=gray,
        thick,
        rectangle split horizontal,
        outer sep = 0pt,
        rectangle split part fill={gray,white},
        inner sep=1pt] (exx) at (0,0)
        {\textcolor{white}{\bfseries\extype}\nodepart{two}\textcolor{black}{\bfseries\theexrc}};
}
```

Comment: Thank you. If I wanted to add a title to this exercise just outside and to the right of the rectangle, how would you go about this?

Comment: Would the downvoter please explain why this answer is not helpful?