# how to make multicol compatible with one column in latex

Tags: multicol

I know there are several latex packages like `exsheets` can make choice problems, but I like to use `multicol` and `enumitem` packages to make them. My little example is as follows:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\newtheorem{ex}{Exercise}

\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\setenumerate{nolistsep}

\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength\multicolsep{0pt}

\begin{document}

\section{Choices}

\begin{ex}
Which letter is a vowel?
\begin{multicols}{4}
\begin{enumerate}[(A)]
\item a
\item b
\item c
\item d
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{ex}

\begin{ex}
Which animal is the best?
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}[(A)]
\item cats
\item dogs
\item horses
\item cows
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{ex}

\begin{ex}
Which mathematical formula do you prefer?
%\begin{multicols}{1}
\begin{enumerate}[(A)]
\item The minimal surface equation
\item The Callan-Symanzik equation
\item Euler's Identity
\item Euler-Lagrange equations and Noether's theorem
\end{enumerate}
%\end{multicols}
\end{ex}

\end{document}
```

Since `\begin{multicols}{1}` is not supported by `multicol` package, one can just comment it and `\end{multicols}` to get the goals. However, if I want to make `multicol`  compatible with one column, then what should I do? Btw, I also note that in [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233866/one-column-multicol-environment) there is a little complex solution can make it. Does there exist a simpler way?

Comment: What's the actual problem with just leaving out the multicols environment when you want a single column? Are you trying to define a custom command that takes the number of columns as an argument? I think that could be solved other ways.